# C++ check if file exists, if yes, change output

Tags: c++, file

I don't know if its relevant, but I'm using Windows 7 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

All I want to do, is ask the user for a filename, check if a file of that name exists, while it does exist, ask them for a different one

**My Attempt**

*Main.cpp*

```
std::cout << std::endl << "You must create a username" << std::endl;
std::cin >> username;
user.checkFile(username);
```

*User.cpp*

```
void User::checkFile(std::string &username)
{

std::ifstream fin (username + ".txt");
    while (fin.good)
    {
    std::cout << "This username already exists, please choose another.";
    std::cin >> username;
     if (fin.bad)
        {
            break;
            fin.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This correctly identifies if a file of that name exists, but then even when I type a name that doesn't exist, it still tells me it does exist

Comment: First of all, `good` and `bad` are functions. Secondly, you can usually just check `fin`. Finally, it's not in a bad state because if it exists, the file is just opened for reading. If not, it's created and opened.

Comment: Plus calling fin.close() after break is pointless - this code is never reached

Comment: @chris:  IIRC, `std::ios_base::in` will *not* create a file on an `std::ifstream` if it does not exist.

Comment: @ZacHowland, Oops, my bad. I was thinking of writing.

Comment: @MartinPerry, And the close is in the destructor anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main.cpp

```
std::cout << std::endl << "You must create a username" << std::endl;
do
{
    std::cin >> username;
    if (user.checkFile(username))
        break;
    std::cout << "This username already exists, please choose another." << std::endl;
}
while (true);
```

User.cpp

```
bool User::checkFile(const std::string &username)
{
    FILE *fin = fopen((username + ".txt").c_str(), "r");
    if (fin)
    {
        fclose(fin);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use simple C function for file handling.

```
void User::checkFile(std::string &username)
{
    std::string username2 = username + ".txt";
    FILE * f = fopen(username2.c_str(), "r");
    while (f != NULL)
    {
      fclose(f);

      std::cout << "This username already exists, please choose another.";
      std::cin >> username;
      std::string username2 = username + ".txt";
      f = fopen(username2.c_str(), "r");          
    }
}
```

This way, yout variable `username` will hold valid name, after function cal returns, because you are passing it via reference.

Comment: brilliant, works fine (after I closed the gap between * and f on the 2nd line of the function)

Comment: Yeh.. sorry, I missed a semicolon there

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(void) {

    bool fileExists = true;

    while (fileExists)
    {
            string fileName;
            cout << "Enter file name: ";
            cin >> fileName;

            ifstream ifs(fileName.c_str());

            fileExists = !ifs.good();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would use a `do/while` loop instead. No need for the `fileExists` variable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You still need a variable outside the loop to test the condition on. If you move `ifs` outside the loop to check it in the terminating condition then you need to do extra work to open/close it correctly. Which is not ideal. It is easier to use `filesExists` external (as a simple bool) the while loop is fine.

Comment: @LokiAstari: no you don't need an outer variable. Enter the `do` and `break` the loop if the file is not found. `do { ifstream ifs(filename); if (!ifs) break; } while (true);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Sure. But that really ugly. Still think the while is totally fine and the above is better than a `do{}while()` loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are limiting yourself to *just* Windows, there is an API function that does exactly that:  [`PathFileExists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want to stick with the standard library, you can do the following:

```
string filename;
cin >> filename;
ifstream fin(filename);
if (fin.is_open())
{
    // file opened successfully
}
else
{
    // file did not open
}
```

Comment: For something closer to the standard, Boost's Filesystem library has it. If using MSVC, the soon-to-be-standard `<filesystem>` header is already there.

Comment: @chris:  True, I almost forgot about that library :)

Answer (score 0):

After inputting the new string, you need to reopen the file with that name:

```
std::cout << "This username already exists, please choose another.";
std::cin >> username;

fin.close();
fin.open(username);
```

Also, `good` and `bad` are functions that must be called using the call operator `()`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will need to convert your string using `c_str()` function. For example:

```
string a="df";
a.c_str(); // will return c string
```

Comment: Not needed in C++11, which this user is most likely using.